# different time in console.time if a function has a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, debugging, console

I've a strange behavior with the console.time function.

I've this test function:

```
function test(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('.test').on('click', function(){
      console.log('clicktest');
    });
  }, 3);
}
```

Additional:

```
console.time('test');
test();
console.timeEnd('test');
```

Now my time with setTimeout and without:

with setTimeout:

```
test: 0.03515625ms
```

without setTimeout:

```
test: 1.44287109375ms
```

I am not sure if this behavior is correct.

I thought I need more time to execute my test function with a setTimeout.

Can somebody explain me this behavior?

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn’t block execution. It runs its callback asynchronously.

Comment: Aaaahh. Okay. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is asynchronous, and by itself requires less computational time to execute than jQuery's methods. In the case of using `setTimeout`, jQuery's methods will be evaluated after the timer has already been stopped.

Comment: Okay. So if I want to track the time of a function with a setTimeout, I can't use console.time?? Is there another way to track the time of a function?

Comment: @cgee If you want to time this, you need to end the timer within the callback function of `setTimeout`, right after the jQuery code.